# making a legacy-mode-only live USB for BIOS-only computer (no UEFI, no dual boot)

Tags: boot, live-usb

I need to ask again this old-fashioned question because the internet is flooded by posts of people struggling with problems contrary to what I have.

**UEFI is totally irrelevant here. Dual boots are totally irrelevant here.**

The **ingredients** are:

- I have an old computer that only works in BIOS mode; it does not have a clue of what UEFI is and will not recognize anything about it (at least as far as I could understand);
- I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 (perhaps a later version) on it;
- legacy mode is what the computer wants.
- the system is 64bit

The **directions** I am asking for are about:

- which image of the Ubuntu distribution should I use?
- where do I find it?
- how should I partition and set up my USB?
- how should I copy the Ubuntu image in the USB?

The desired **result** is that, at boot time, plugging such an USB drive starts the Ubuntu installer.

Again, doing this with from the UEFI perspective works fine for me; I lack information on this corner 'retro' situation.

Comment: There's a nice guide about that [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS).You have to download special images.But you cannot update it because it might install grub2 meanwhile and that makes it unable to boot in your legacy BIOS system.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi It seems that that post deals principally with UEFI-and-BIOS, but I am interested in **BIOS only**. This is because the computer does not have a clue of what UEFI is and simply does not recognize anything like that; for it UEFI is still future. Also, personally, I find the layout of that site and its linkages with external resources a bit too messy for such a delicate action as a system installation.

Comment: How old is system? How much RAM. If less than 4GB you may want Lubuntu. I was able to install 20.04 into my 2006 Laptop with 1.5GB of RAM, but full Ubuntu would not install at all, but server image did install & I added fallback/gnome-panel for a lightweight install.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the Lubuntu tip. I found an answer that works for me on https://askubuntu.com/a/1254808/446253

Comment: What most "solutions" have in common is that _all_ they do is write an ISO onto a USB storage device. The fact that they "work" is because the user has downloaded a BIOS-compatible ISO, which is what we need help locating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is straightforward and all shipped by Ubuntu.
Please look up for the 'Startup Disk Creator' application in the launchpad.
A GUI will ask you which ISO image you want to copy into which drive (that is, a USB drive mounted in the USB port).

I was in another UEFI-capable computer with Ubuntu 16.04.
I downloaded the ISO of the target release (14.04) from https://releases.ubuntu.com/ and use the Startup Disk Creator.
The USB created this way is a working live USB and has immediately been recognized by the old BIOS computer.

Thanks to https://web.archive.org/web/20200713232146/https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/, halfway down the page.

Answer (score 3):

### Bios Only Ubuntu Installer

Download Ubuntu 20.04 https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Start with a USB of at least 4GB formatted FAT32.

If using Windows, download Rufus. https://rufus.ie/

Double click the Rufus .exe file, no need to install.

[image]

Select USB Device and ISO file for Boot Selection.

Select `START`

When Rufus is done use USB to install Ubuntu to BIOS or UEFI machine.

Comment: This answer is specific for people starting off from Windows.